# ¿Configurar un <select> sin usar php?

Tags: html, select

Actualmente tengo una situación que realmente puede que no sea la gran cosa, pero he tratado de buscar por todas partes y realmente no he encontrado la respuesta a mi problema.

Bien, todos sabemos que la etiqueta `<select>` sirve para crear una lista de `<option>`, estoy trabajando en JavaScript con un código basado en HTLM, ya que estoy haciendo una página con elementos dinámicos que no necesiten recargar la página para cumplir su función, por ese motivo no quiero meterle PHP al código, ya que PHP necesita que se recargue la página para sus funciones, el problema radica en que no tengo la menor idea de que hacer luego de definir las posibles opciones del select.

```html
<select id="opcion" required>
  <option value="1">boton 1</option>
  <option value="2">boton 2</option>
</select>
```

lo que quisiera hacer es que al seleccionarse la primera opción muestre un botón y que luego si presiono la segunda opción, oculte el primer botón y cree uno nuevo.

Los botones si sé como configurarlos, realmente esta pregunta es simple y corta, pero no encuentro en ningún lugar como aplicar las condiciones del select, trate con un `IF`, pero no pasó nada.

Comment: Usas jquery en tu proyecto?

Comment: De momento no he usado jquery en el proyecto, solo funciones script, vi que hay una forma de activar funciones mediante PHP pero eso me fuerza a tener que actualizar la página,  yo quiero que todo sea de modo dinámico.

Comment: Gabriel, bienvenido. Primeramente quiero aclarar que tienes una confusión: *ya que estoy haciendo una página con elementos dinámicos que no necesiten recargar la página para cumplir su función, por ese motivo no quiero meterle PHP al código, ya que PHP necesita que se recargue la página para sus funciones*   .... Realmente **es posible usar código PHP sin recargar la página, mediante Ajax**. Ahora bien, solamente **debes hacerlo con PHP si necesitas algo del servidor**, si no necesitas nada del servidor perfecto, lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer desde Javascript.

Comment: No necesito nada del servidor, así que si es posible, me gustaría hacerlo con javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta pregunta ya había sido respondida en al menos una pregunta en ingles: [Jquery enable/disable button based on select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346044/jquery-enable-disable-button-based-on-select-option)

```
$('#picker').on('change', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).val()).prop('disabled', false)
      .siblings().prop('disabled', true);
});​
```

Con esa respuesta, se incluye un ejemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/vZacx/

En tu caso, si deseas esconder los botones, puedes usar show/hide:

```
$('#picker').on('change', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show()
      .siblings().hide();
});​
```

Comment: Gracias por hacer de mi conocimiento esa pregunta, al menos ahora cualquiera que lo busque en español podrá dar con eso más fácilmente.